# Why can't i call this function with my variables?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to call a function with two variables:

```
$('#sub-nav li a').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(event);

    // Which slider to use
    var $sliderNo = $(this).attr('data-slider');
    var $slider = "#flexslider" + $sliderNo;

    // Which slide to show
    var $slide = $(this).attr('data-slide');

    // Lets say i click on the link for slider 1, and the link for slide 1:
    alert($slide); // This will alert correct data-slide number
    alert($slider); // This will alert: '#flexslider1'

    $("#flexslider1").flexslider(1); //This will run!
    $($slider).flexslider($slide); // This won't run! - Why?
});
```

Why can't i call `$($slider).flexslider($slide);` with the $variables?

Comment: try using `parseInt($slide, 10);`

Comment: Can you show your HTML or a fiddle. Use `parseInt()` for numbers.

Comment: Isn't `$($slider).flexslider($slideNo);` what you need?

Comment: Also, when using jQuery, the convention is to apply `$` to variables that hold a reference to jQuery-wrapped elements. Your `$sliderNo` and `$slider` are both `string`.

Comment: Could it be that it's a problem with this flexslider plugin? I just created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xwyv5/) and it works perfectly (with a mock for flexslider).

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('#sub-nav li a').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Which slider to use
    var $sliderNo = $(this).data('slider');
    var $slider = "#flexslider" + $sliderNo;

    // Which slide to show
    var $slide = $(this).data('slide');

    // Lets say i click on the link for slider 1, and the link for slide 1:
    alert($slide); // This will alert correct data-slide number
    alert($slider); // This will alert: '#flexslider1'

    $("#flexslider1").flexslider(1); //This will run!
    $($slider).flexslider($slide); // This won't run! - Why?
});
```

Comment: If you use (as OP should) data object property, value should be already parsed to number, unlike using attribute which returns string. You shouldn't have to parse it again. Anyway +1. I meant, here `$($slider).flexslider($slide);` should work. BTW `event.preventDefault(event);` no need to pass any parameter

Comment: @A.Wolff - Thanks for your proper guidence. I understood